# How to filter a bootstrap vue table with an input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

The title says it all. I want to filter my bootstrap table with an input box.

Here is my **.html** part of the component:

```
<b-table
:items="Table"
:fields="fields"
striped
small
>

</b-table>
```

Here is the **.vue** file

```
<template src="./jointable.component.html"> </template>
<style scoped src="./jointable.component.css"> </style>


<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'jointable',
    data(){
        return {
            Table: [],
            fields: [
                {key: 'client_id', label: "School Code", sortable: true},
                {key: 'client_name', sortable: true},
                {key: 'uuid', label: "ID", sortable: true},
                {key: 'step', label: "Job Running", sortable: true},
                {key: 'serverid', sortable: true},
                {key: 'create_timestamp', label: "Job Start", sortable: true},
                {key: 'time_elapsed', sortable: true},
                {key: 'wh_db_host', sortable: true}
            ]
        }
    },
    methods : {
        loadData: function(){
            axios.get("http://192.168.56.101:5000/jointable")
            .then((res) => {
                this.Table = res.data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadData();

        setInterval(function(){
            this.loadData()
        }.bind(this), 10000)
    },
    computed() {

    }
}
</script>
```

So right now you can see that my script reloads the table every 10 seconds with updated data. This is fine. I want to also now have my table searchable/filterable. I know I have to use the computed thing but how do I use it.

Thank you to whoever helps me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's various ways to filter, but the most simple version is simply passing in a string to the `filter` prop on `b-table`.

This will search all columns for the string you pass in, so if you bind a data property to a input's `v-model` and the same data property to the `filter` property on your table, anything you type in the input will filter the table.

You can read more about how filtering works and some of the other methods in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#filtering).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      filter: '',
      items: [
        { id: 1, first_name: "Mikkel", last_name: "Hansen", age: 54 },
        { id: 2, first_name: "Kasper", last_name: "Hvidt", age: 42 },
        { id: 3, first_name: "Lasse", last_name: "Boesen", age: 39 },
        { id: 4, first_name: "Kasper", last_name: "Hansen", age: 62 },
        { id: 5, first_name: "Mads", last_name: "Mikkelsen", age: 31 },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Filter table.."></b-input>
  <hr />
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" :filter="filter">
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this really helpful. I actually found this after reading over the documentation again. (I probably should of done that before asking a question here).

Answer (score 1):

Detailed Code for filtering bootstrap-vue please refer [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table)  Thanks

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          isActive: true,
          age: 40,
          name: {
            first: 'Dickerson',
            last: 'Macdonald'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 21,
          name: {
            first: 'Larsen',
            last: 'Shaw'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 9,
          name: {
            first: 'Mini',
            last: 'Navarro'
          },
          _rowVariant: 'success'
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 89,
          name: {
            first: 'Geneva',
            last: 'Wilson'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 38,
          name: {
            first: 'Jami',
            last: 'Carney'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 27,
          name: {
            first: 'Essie',
            last: 'Dunlap'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 40,
          name: {
            first: 'Thor',
            last: 'Macdonald'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 87,
          name: {
            first: 'Larsen',
            last: 'Shaw'
          },
          _cellVariants: {
            age: 'danger',
            isActive: 'warning'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 26,
          name: {
            first: 'Mitzi',
            last: 'Navarro'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 22,
          name: {
            first: 'Genevieve',
            last: 'Wilson'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 38,
          name: {
            first: 'John',
            last: 'Carney'
          }
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 29,
          name: {
            first: 'Dick',
            last: 'Dunlap'
          }
        }
      ],
      fields: [{
          key: 'name',
          label: 'Person full name',
          sortable: true,
          sortDirection: 'desc'
        },
        {
          key: 'age',
          label: 'Person age',
          sortable: true,
          class: 'text-center'
        },
        {
          key: 'isActive',
          label: 'Is Active',
          formatter: (value, key, item) => {
            return value ? 'Yes' : 'No'
          },
          sortable: true,
          sortByFormatted: true,
          filterByFormatted: true
        },
        {
          key: 'actions',
          label: 'Actions'
        }
      ],
      totalRows: 1,
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 5,
      pageOptions: [5, 10, 15, {
        value: 100,
        text: "Show a lot"
      }],
      sortBy: '',
      sortDesc: false,
      sortDirection: 'asc',
      filter: null,
      filterOn: [],
      infoModal: {
        id: 'info-modal',
        title: '',
        content: ''
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortOptions() {
      // Create an options list from our fields
      return this.fields
        .filter(f => f.sortable)
        .map(f => {
          return {
            text: f.label,
            value: f.key
          }
        })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Set the initial number of items
    this.totalRows = this.items.length
  },
  methods: {
    info(item, index, button) {
      this.infoModal.title = `Row index: ${index}`
      this.infoModal.content = JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)
      this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', this.infoModal.id, button)
    },
    resetInfoModal() {
      this.infoModal.title = ''
      this.infoModal.content = ''
    },
    onFiltered(filteredItems) {
      // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
      this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
      this.currentPage = 1
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <template>
  <b-container fluid>
    <!-- User Interface controls -->
    <b-row>
      <b-col lg="6" class="my-1">
        <b-form-group
          label="Sort"
          label-for="sort-by-select"
          label-cols-sm="3"
          label-align-sm="right"
          label-size="sm"
          class="mb-0"
          v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }"
        >
          <b-input-group size="sm">
            <b-form-select
              id="sort-by-select"
              v-model="sortBy"
              :options="sortOptions"
              :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
              class="w-75"
            >
              <template #first>
                <option value="">-- none --</option>
              </template>
  </b-form-select>

  <b-form-select v-model="sortDesc" :disabled="!sortBy" :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby" size="sm" class="w-25">
    <option :value="false">Asc</option>
    <option :value="true">Desc</option>
  </b-form-select>
  </b-input-group>
  </b-form-group>
  </b-col>

  <b-col lg="6" class="my-1">
    <b-form-group label="Initial sort" label-for="initial-sort-select" label-cols-sm="3" label-align-sm="right" label-size="sm" class="mb-0">
      <b-form-select id="initial-sort-select" v-model="sortDirection" :options="['asc', 'desc', 'last']" size="sm"></b-form-select>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>

  <b-col lg="6" class="my-1">
    <b-form-group label="Filter" label-for="filter-input" label-cols-sm="3" label-align-sm="right" label-size="sm" class="mb-0">
      <b-input-group size="sm">
        <b-form-input id="filter-input" v-model="filter" type="search" placeholder="Type to Search"></b-form-input>

        <b-input-group-append>
          <b-button :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-button>
        </b-input-group-append>
      </b-input-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>

  <b-col lg="6" class="my-1">
    <b-form-group v-model="sortDirection" label="Filter On" description="Leave all unchecked to filter on all data" label-cols-sm="3" label-align-sm="right" label-size="sm" class="mb-0" v-slot="{ ariaDescribedby }">
      <b-form-checkbox-group v-model="filterOn" :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby" class="mt-1">
        <b-form-checkbox value="name">Name</b-form-checkbox>
        <b-form-checkbox value="age">Age</b-form-checkbox>
        <b-form-checkbox value="isActive">Active</b-form-checkbox>
      </b-form-checkbox-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>

  <b-col sm="5" md="6" class="my-1">
    <b-form-group label="Per page" label-for="per-page-select" label-cols-sm="6" label-cols-md="4" label-cols-lg="3" label-align-sm="right" label-size="sm" class="mb-0">
      <b-form-select id="per-page-select" v-model="perPage" :options="pageOptions" size="sm"></b-form-select>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>

  <b-col sm="7" md="6" class="my-1">
    <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" align="fill" size="sm" class="my-0"></b-pagination>
  </b-col>
  </b-row>

  <!-- Main table element -->
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="perPage" :filter="filter" :filter-included-fields="filterOn" :sort-by.sync="sortBy" :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc" :sort-direction="sortDirection" stacked="md" show-empty small
    @filtered="onFiltered">
    <template #cell(name)="row">
        {{ row.value.first }} {{ row.value.last }}
      </template>

    <template #cell(actions)="row">
        <b-button size="sm" @click="info(row.item, row.index, $event.target)" class="mr-1">
          Info modal
        </b-button>
        <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails">
          {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Details
        </b-button>
      </template>

    <template #row-details="row">
        <b-card>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="(value, key) in row.item" :key="key">{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
          </ul>
        </b-card>
      </template>
  </b-table>

  <!-- Info modal -->
  <b-modal :id="infoModal.id" :title="infoModal.title" ok-only @hide="resetInfoModal">
    <pre>{{ infoModal.content }}</pre>
  </b-modal>
  </b-container>
  </template>


</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  Items: [
  {Name: 'Lorem ipsum'},
  {Name: 'consectetur'},
  {Name: 'adipisicing.'}
  ],
  search: ''
  },
  computed: {
  filteredItems() {
  return this.Items.filter(item => item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))
  }
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.search {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
p {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
<p>Found {{filteredItems.length}} items</p>
  <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" v-model="search">
  <div class="item" v-for="item in filteredItems">{{item.Name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was asking how to do it with bootstrap vue. No sorry this isn't it.