# Filter BootstrapVue table using comma separated string with OR condition in input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a BootstrapVue table that looks like this;

[image]

The code(credit goes to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611279/how-to-filter-a-bootstrap-vue-table-with-an-input-field/60613741#60613741)) for the table is here;

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      filter: '',
      items: [
        { id: 1, first_name: "Mikkel", last_name: "Hansen", age: 54 },
        { id: 2, first_name: "Kasper", last_name: "Hvidt", age: 42 },
        { id: 3, first_name: "Lasse", last_name: "Boesen", age: 39 },
        { id: 4, first_name: "Kasper", last_name: "Hansen", age: 62 },
        { id: 5, first_name: "Mads", last_name: "Mikkelsen", age: 31 },
      ]
    }
  }
})

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Filter table.."></b-input>
  <hr />
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" :filter="filter">
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Based on the above code, table rows will be filtered based on the string inside the input field. Unfortunately, this is not what I want. What I want is for the input field to be able to accept a comma-separated string and the sub-strings can be used to filter the table rows in an OR condition. For example, if the string is `54, Hvidt`, then the first and second rows will be filtered.

I am using BootstrapVue, vue.js 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BootstrapVue allows writing your own logic for filtering, using a [custom filter function](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-filter-function).

In order for it to work, you need:

- a `:filter` specified
- the `filter` value to be truthy. If it's falsey, the filter function is bypassed (no filtering occurs).
- a `:filter-function` specified, taking two arguments: `row` and current `filter` value (optional and not needed: you can read it from `this.filter`).

Here's an example, splitting current `filter` value by `,` (comma), normalising the fragments (`trim` & `toLowerCase`), and returning whether or not any fragment is found within the normalised values of the row.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      filter: '54, Hvidt',
      items: [
        { id: 1, first_name: "Mikkel", last_name: "Hansen", age: 54 },
        { id: 2, first_name: "Kasper", last_name: "Hvidt", age: 42 },
        { id: 3, first_name: "Lasse", last_name: "Boesen", age: 39 },
        { id: 4, first_name: "Kasper", last_name: "Hansen", age: 62 },
        { id: 5, first_name: "Mads", last_name: "Mikkelsen", age: 31 }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    normalizeString(s) {
      return `${s}`.trim().toLowerCase();
    },
    filterFn(row) {
      return this.filter.split(',')
        .map(this.normalizeString)
        .some(
          term => Object.values(row)
            .map(this.normalizeString)
            .some(
              val => val.indexOf(term) > -1
            )
        );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.6.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Filter table..."></b-input>
  <hr />
  <b-table :items="items" :filter="filter" :filter-function="filterFn">
  </b-table>
</div>
```

**Important note**: the filter function provided here is *demonstrative*, it doesn't take into account BootstrapVue's built-in `filter-ignored-fields` and `filter-included-fields`. Nor does it take into account the `filterByFormatted` [field definition](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#field-definition-reference).

If you need any of those features, you'll need to improve it yourself.

I guess it's needless to point out the filter function has access to the entire component and can be modified in any way. The `row` is displayed if the function returns a truthy value and is not displayed if it returns a falsey value.

Comment: #tao Thanks. Your solution is brilliant. It will take me some time to understand it. I'm not familiar with the map() function and some() is something new to me.

Comment: @user, [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns true when the first array member satisfying the condition is met (so it's cheap, it doesn't go through the entire array). [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is fairly straight forward. Keep MDN close, it's a high quality beginner friendly resource for all web technologies. Whenever you don't understand something, use breakpoints and/or `console.log()` every step, until it's clear what each one does.